# Unexpected Coffeescript transformation with if?

Tags: coffeescript, conditional-operator

This CoffeeScript:

```
x = y > z ? 'a' : 'b'
```

[Compiles to](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3ax%20=%20y%20%3E%20z%20?%20%27a%27%20%3a%20%27b%27%0A):

```
x = (_ref = y > z) != null ? _ref : {
  'a': 'b'
};
```

I assume this is expected, just not intuitive.

This there a better way to do this in coffeescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CoffeeScript's `?` operator is the existence operator ("soak" or "elvis" names are also used).
exemple : `context = window ? global`.

The CoffeeScript way of doing it is `x = if x > z then 'a' else 'b'` (or `x = x > z and 'a' or 'b'`, but the "and" operand must be truthy for this to work) which will compile down to the ternary operator you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if` instead of `?:`:

```
x = if y > z then 'a' else 'b'
```

this [compiles to](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3ax%20=%20y%20%3E%20z%20?%20%27a%27%20%3a%20%27b%27%0A)

```
var x;

x = y > z ? 'a' : 'b';
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what I want, but I don't know if I happy with it.

Coffeescript:

```
x = if y > z then 'a' else 'b'
```

Javascript

```
x = y > z ? 'a' : 'b';
```